# Sorting on multiple columns and ignoring fields in vim

Tags: shell, sorting, vim

is it possible to sort on multiple columns and ignore certain lines starting with # ?
I have my a text like this:

```
#Comments
#More comments
foo;1;1
foo;3;2
bar;2;1
```

I'd like to sort on the first number and if those are equal on the last number.
I tried this:

```
:%!sort -t';' -k2n -k3n
```

but this will affect the comments section.
I know i can make vim ignore the comments like this:

```
:sort /^#/
```

but how do i select the fields now??
Does the shell sort have a field ignorer? Or can the VIM sort use fields?

BTW the comments section's length can increase so head/tail won't work.

Comment: If the comments are just at the top you can just pass a range to either of the sort commands

Comment: They are just the top but more comment lines might be added in the future and the idea is that the commands stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that

```
:sort /^#/
```

does what you want.  It will sort the comments, putting them at the end of the buffer, and leave the other lines in the original order.  A lot closer to what you want is

```
:sort /;/
```

This will leave all comments at the top of the buffer, in the original order, and sort on the part of the line after the first <kbd>;</kbd>.  Probably lexicographic sort is not what you want.  Instead, you could use

```
:sort /;/ n
```

This will do numeric sort, but ignore the part of the line after the first number.

In order to avoid sorting comment lines that happen to contain <kbd>;</kbd> characters, you could use a more complicated pattern:

```
:sort /^\(\s*#\)\@!.\{-};/ n
```

or (using a feature that I may never have tried before)

```
:sort /^\s*[^#]\&.\{-\};/ n
```

I am old-school, and use vim's default settings, but a lot of people prefer the `\v` (very magic) setting.  That makes these a little simpler:

```
:sort /\v^(\s*#)@!.{-};/ n
:sort /\v^\s*[^#]&.{-};/ n
```

OTOH, the version you suggested using the external sort seems to work perfectly.

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunatly there are also ;'s in the comments.

Comment: Then you need a slightly more complicated pattern.  I will edit my answer.